# How to change the pseudocode into real code?

Tags: bash

There are four time servers, i want to  synchronize local time with ntp time server.

```
arr=(s2c.time.edu.cn s2d.time.edu.cn s2e.time.edu.cn s2f.time.edu.cn) 
for var in ${arr[@]};
do
   # two lines pseudocode  here
   if `ntpdate $var` secceed ,exit the for loop
   if none of ntp time server can be used,echo "failure"
done
```

How to change the pseudocode into real code?
I fix the flaw with codes:

```
arr=(s2c.time.edu.cn s2d.time.edu.cn s2e.time.edu.cn s2f.time.edu.cn) 
switch = 0 
for var in ${arr[@]};
do
   # one lines pseudocode  here
   if `ntpdate $var` secceed ,assign switch = 1 ,exit the for loop
done
if["$switch" = "0"] ;then
    echo "synchronize local time with ntpdate failure"
fi
```

How to change `if`ntpdate $var`secceed ,assign switch = 1 ,exit the for loop` into real bash script?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed algorithm has an obvious flaw:

> - loop over servers
>
>   - if ntp server can be used -> exit loop
>   - if none of ntp server can be used -> echo failure

The flaw is the last step, "if none of the ntp servers ...".
It doesn't make sense to have this inside the loop,
because you cannot judge that until you finished the loop.

Consider this instead:

- create a function
- loop over servers

  - if ntp server can be used -> return from the function with success
- if none of ntp server can be used -> return from the function with failure

Implementation:

```
use_any_ntp_server() {
    for server; do
       ntpdate $server && return
    done
    return 1
}

if ! use_any_server s2c.time.edu.cn s2d.time.edu.cn s2e.time.edu.cn s2f.time.edu.cn; then
    echo failure: none of the ntp servers could be used
fi
```